# Merge an arbitrary number of dictionaries of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

How could dictionaries whose values are lists be merged in Python, so that all of the keys are moved into one dictionary, and all the elements of each list moved into a single list for each key?

For example, with these dictionaries:

```
x = {'a': [2], 'b': [2]}
y = {'b': [11], 'c': [11]}
```

... the result of the merging should be like this:

```
{'a': [2], 'b': [2, 11], 'c': [11]}
```

How could this be done with any number of dictionaries, not just two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To collect all the lists together, form a *result* dictionary that maps your keys to lists.  The simplest way to do this is with [*dict.setdefault()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) followed by a call to [*list.extend*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) to grow the lists:

```
r = {}
for d in [x, y]:
    for k, v in d.items():
        r.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
```

A little more elegant way is with [*collections.defaultdict()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) where the automatic default is a new empty list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

r = defaultdict(list)
for d in [x, y]:
    for k, v in d.items():
        r[k].extend(v)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use following approach, which uses `sets` and `dict comprehension`

```
x = {'a': [2], 'b': [2]} 
y = {'b': [11], 'c': [11]}

all_keys = set(x) | set(y)

print {k:x.get(k, [])+y.get(k, []) for k in all_keys}
```

Results:

```
{'a': [2], 'c': [11], 'b': [2, 11]}
```

Comment: `all_keys = set(x) | set(y)` would work in both 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks @DSM Plus I even don't like `.keys()` method.

Comment: @DSM  Missed that  :)

Comment: Why not just get rid of all_keys? The expression is short/easy enough to just put in the comprehension directly.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: ehh, not worth worrying about.  Plus if we wanted to do the generalized version (with an arbitrary number of dicts) it would be clearer to work with separate variables anyhow.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: That's just to make the statements more understandable.

Comment: @DSM Someone (not the OP) actually just changed the question to the general case, pretending it to be *"formatting, removed unclear explanation"*. Is that ok? It invalidates all answers.

Comment: @Stefan OP did in fact ask for a solution for N dictionaries in the unedited question: "and the result should turn out to be like this, but **how do I work this out with any amount of dictionaries**" (my emphasis).

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Oh, right, I missed that as it was kinda hidden and the edit moved it elsewhere. I'm not convinced this is what the OP meant, though, since the title clearly and specifically asked about *two* dictionaries and the OP clearly didn't know how to do that. I suspect he didn't actually mean number of dictionaries there, but *size* of dictionaries or number of lists inside them or so.

Answer (score 5):

```
for k, v in y.items():
    x.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works for an arbitrary number of dictionaries:

```
def collect(*dicts):
    result = {}
    for key in set.union(*(set(d) for d in dicts)):
        result[key] = sum((d.get(key, []) for d in dicts), [])
    return result
```

It's essentially a generalisation of Tanveer's answer, taking advantage of the fact that [`set.union()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) can accept any number of dictionaries as arguments.

Here's an example of the function in use:

```
>>> x = {'a': [2], 'b': [2]}
>>> y = {'b': [11], 'c': [11]}
>>> collect(x, y)
{'a': [2], 'c': [11], 'b': [2, 11]}
```

... and with multiple dictionaries:

```
>>> z = {'c': [12, 13], 'd': [5]}
>>> collect(x, y, z)
{'a': [2], 'c': [11, 12, 13], 'b': [2, 11], 'd': [5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
x = {'a': [2], 'b': [2]}
y = {'b': [11], 'c': [11]}
result = {}
for key,value in x.iteritems():
    result[key] = value
for key,value in y.iteritems():
    if key in result:
        for l in value:
            result[key].append(l)
    else:
        result[key] = value
print result
```